# Looking for a very last minute adventure trip (5th -13th May)

Tags: uk, adventure, activities, outdoor-activities, short-notice

Basically, due to a break up and cancellation of previous arrangements, I find myself with a free week next week and I really fancy doing something active and outdoors. Most of my trips recently have been scenery, cities and museums, so I'd like to try something more adventurous. I've tried some of the adventure travel places online, but most have been fully booked, or it's too late for the dates I need, so I'd like a recommendation for a place that I can head to and just arrange to do various things there on my own. I'm looking for things like white water rafting, kayaking/canoeing, mountain biking, trekking... maybe para-sailing, bungee jumping... I'm generally open to any ideas that don't involve museums and galleries :P

I'm in the UK, and only have a week (9 days at most, Saturday to Sunday) so somewhere that doesn't take too long to get to would be ideal. If there was one place I could head to to do multiple activities, that would be great, and I'm open to splitting the time between a couple of locations. Budget wise, cheaper would be great, but last minute will always cost more so not really a requirement, and happy to pay more for something that's truly awesome. Any advice would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Central and North Wales, or the Scottish Highlands both spring to mind as places to start looking. Some of the lower bits of the alps should have started their summer stuff by now, could be worth looking at too if you can get there cheaply

Comment: Keep Scotland as last option. Spring this year has not been a good one. Lots of rain and there was even a snow shower couple of weeks ago. :)

Comment: @Prashanth sounds like good conditions for some white water rafting!

Comment: As worded this is definitely "too localized" since it refers to a specific date range, which is now in the past. Is there a way to re-word it to ever be of use to others?

Comment: @hippietrail "Outdoor activities within or very close to the UK"

Answer (score 7):

Go to the [Ardennes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ardennes) in Belgium. Since it is almost our backgarden, we go there often as a last minute decision. It is a large area and there are really a lot of outdoor activities. There are really a lot of kayaking being offered around the different rivers. Good starting points for exploring are [Dinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinant), [La Roche-en-ardenne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Roche-en-Ardenne), or [Yvoir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yvoir).

[image]

A disadvantage might be that most website advertising activities are only in French and Dutch. (See: [example](http://www.ardenne-aventures.be/nl/home.html)). You need websites for a first impression, but once you have found your way to the Ardennes, you know that the nice thing about the Ardennes is that you can just go unprepared. Google translate might be your friend for first impressions.

[image]

Getting to the Ardennes from the UK is easy. You can take the car ferry from Dover to Dunkerque/Calais, Ramsgate to Oostende, or Harwich - Hoek van Holland or take the shuttle between felixstowe and Calais.

You could also fly into Brussels/Antwerp and rent a car at the airport. A car is a necessity to visit the Ardennes.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to stay in the UK?

Maybe you could go hiking and camping in [Dartmoor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmoor). I've always wanted to, but never found the right time... That place seems amazing.

Answer (score 2):

In the future if you want to get involved in outdoor activities, [Factivities](http://www.factivities.co.uk/) is the UK’s original and largest online directory of outdoor activities, outdoor pursuits and Activity Centres. With over 16,000 activities located throughout the UK, you are bound to find, or mix n' match activities and locations for whatever is the duration of your stay.