# Must see places while going through Belgium?

Tags: sightseeing, belgium

I'm going to travel by car from Netherlands to Luxemburg. Whole round-trip starts from the Baltics - Germany - Netherlands - Belgum - Luxemburg - towards Baltics. I'm not in a hurry and I would like to spend some time sightseeing.

I'm not looking for "just beautiful" buildings, famous statues, amusement parks or similar places where one could spend their all day and all their money.

Some examples from another countries I liked: Hill of crosses in Lithuania, Wieliczka(in Poland) salt mine, windmills in Netherlands, some great Castles   - things that make you go "wow" one way or another

What are a must-see places in Belgium?

Comment: From where in the Netherlands are you traveling?

Comment: Visit Bruges/Brugge. Drink trappist beers. Eat dark chocolate.

Comment: @lejohn I've edited my post about my route. I would like to pass through in a flowing manner. Meaning that I possibly avoid far-far corners of a any country and would stick to the side what connects from to destination side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The must-see places in Belgium are the big cities, like [Brussels](http://wikitravel.org/en/Brussels), [Antwerp](http://wikitravel.org/en/Antwerp) and [Ghent](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ghent). Okay, you could also add [Bruges](http://wikitravel.org/en/Bruges) to that list. But don't go to Bruges without going to Ghent. The latter has a real life with real persons, not only tourists. And it has a nice [medieval castle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravensteen).

If you want more specific advice, here are 10 interesting things do to and places to visit. If you come to Belgium via Roosendaal, and you want to continue to Luxembourg, all these places are more or less along the road.

- A canal cruise in Ghent is interesting and gives you a nice perspective of the city.
- The [Flemish Béguinages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9guinage) are part of the UNESCO world heritage. Why not visiting the one in [Leuven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leuven)?
- In [Mechelen](http://wikitravel.org/en/Mechelen), climb up the tower of [St. Rumbold's Cathedral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Rumbold%27s_Cathedral) and see the carillon at work.
- If you go to the capital of the European Union, visit the [European Parliament](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/visiting/en/).
- Belgium has an important colonial history. A visit to the [Royal Museum for Central Africa](http://www.africamuseum.be/) is very instructive. It is located in Tervuren, on the outskirts of Brussels.
- While in Brussels, sample Belgian beer at [Moeder Lambic](http://www.moederlambic.com/bars/fr/bars/) or [Bier Circus](http://www.bier-circus.be/).
- Belgium is not only about chocolate and beer. When driving from Brussels to Luxembourg, visit the [Hergé Museum](http://www.museeherge.com/en) in [Louvain-la-Neuve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louvain-la-Neuve) (+- 30 kilometers from Brussels).
- The [Waterloo battlefield](http://www.waterloo1815.be/) is not far from Brussels.
- If you like caves, stop in [Han-sur-Lesse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caves_of_Han-sur-Lesse), on your way to Luxembourg. It's not a big detour.
- The [Orval abbey](http://www.orval.be/), home of one of the world's best beers is located in the southeast of the country, not too far from Luxembourg.

Comment: I really like some of the things you've pointed out. I've added St. Rumbold's Cathedral, Royal Museum for Central Africa, Ghent with it's medieval castle, Hans-Sur-Lesse and Orval Abbey to my route. Really good answer and I thank you for it.

Answer (score 8):

Bruges/Brugge is a must see.

As you come from Netherlands, you won't go "Wow" on the bike friendly town. But there are windmills, a beautiful belfry with its carillon that you can visit. There are many canals in this Venice of the North. There are also a chocolate museum and a diamond museum (only the former offers samples to visitors). You can even see the relic of the Holy Blood and the building of the bourse, the first stock exchange in the world.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Bruges/Brugge seems a good recommendation. Chocolate & Diamond museums are good but from Google I find that there are numerous different museums for each. Any idea which one of them makes me go "Wow" and makes me suggest that for everybody who asks me what they should see in Belgium?

Comment: I visited only the ones in Brugge. I guess that diamond is better celebrated in Antwerp/Antwerpen.

Answer (score 7):

In Belgium you can stay in a [castle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/4324/141)

I guess you will be traveling by train. This way you are limited to Antwerp, Brussels, Gent and Brugge. Let me start with some tips from my home town Antwerp.

1. The [ruien](http://www.visitantwerpen.be/Bezoekerssite-EN/Publicatiekanalen/Stad/Antwerpenbe/Bezoekerssites/Bezoekerssite-EN/Bezoekerssite-EN-Bezoekerssite-EN/Bezoekerssite-EN-Bezoekerssite-EN-Doelgroepnavigatie/Visitors/to-do/Visitors-to-do-attractions/Visitors-to-do-attractions-ruien.html). Antwerp has a century old sewage system which is open to visitors. A visit comprises of two walks. First you'll go down in to the sewer system, where the trip start with a short boat trip, then you walk underneath the city, while a guide explains where you are and some other interesting stories. The second part is where you walk the same tour, but now from outside.
2. [The Vlaaykens gang](https://maps.google.be/maps?q=The%20vlaaikensgang&hl=nl&ll=51.220755,4.399424&spn=0.007392,0.016136&hq=The%20vlaaikensgang&hnear=Antwerpen,%20Vlaams%20Gewest&t=m&z=16) This a small road right in the center of Antwerp, where you'll think you are in medieval times.
3. [De Pelgrom/Poorterswoning](http://www.pelgrom.be/). De poorterswoning is a very small but remarkable museum. It only opens in the weekend. You'll be visiting a house of merchant from the past. In the cellar of this museum you'll find a pub call De Pelgrom.

Things to do in Brussels

1. Visit the [atomium](http://atomium.be/FoodAndDrinks.aspx?lang=en)
2. Visit [Manneke pis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manneken_Pis) (the eifel tower of Brussels).
3. Visit [Jeanneke pis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeanneke_Pis) The less known sister of Manneke pis.
4. Visit the [sunday](http://www.abatan.be/en) market in Anderlecht. This is of the beaten track. You'll find your self in a different atmosphere with a multitude of cultures. [Google maps](https://maps.google.be/maps?q=slachthuis%20anderlecht&hl=nl&ll=50.841896,4.33004&spn=0.003726,0.008068&hq=slachthuis&hnear=Anderlecht,%20Brussel&t=m&fll=50.841896,4.33004&fspn=0.003726,0.008068&z=17). Metro: Clemanceau
5. Visit the [natural science museum](http://www.naturalsciences.be/index_html). With an impressive collection (of which some impressive dinosaurs skeletons).

If you are not limited by traveling by train, others Belgian beauties can be found in:

1. [Lier](https://maps.google.be/maps?q=lier&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x47c3fc63b318c329:0x6ae7fc52ac33a641,Lier&gl=be&ei=k-_TT5aJBcrQ-gbjydCuBA&oi=geocode_result&ved=0CCAQ8gEwAg): With its [Wonder clock by Louis Zimmer](http://www.toerismelier.be/pages/ontdekken_.php?level1=1&level2=1&level3=100)
2. [Westmalle Brewery](http://www.trappistwestmalle.be/en/page/brouwerij.aspx)
3. [Boullion](https://maps.google.be/maps?hl=nl&q=hasselt&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x47c12183ded75db7:0xf7cb7b027e7e2181,Hasselt&gl=be&ei=6e_TT72NH5CG-waSgdX9Aw&oi=geocode_result&sqi=2&ved=0CBIQ8gEwAw) Here you will find your castle.
4. [Dinant](https://maps.google.be/maps?q=Dinant&hl=nl&ie=UTF8&sll=49.794664,5.070759&sspn=0.121894,0.258179&gl=be&hnear=Dinant,%20Namen,%20R%C3%A9gion%20wallonne&t=m&z=12)
5. [Hasselt and it surroundings](https://maps.google.be/maps?hl=nl&q=hasselt&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x47c12183ded75db7:0xf7cb7b027e7e2181,Hasselt&gl=be&ei=6e_TT72NH5CG-waSgdX9Aw&oi=geocode_result&sqi=2&ved=0CBIQ8gEwAw) Of which [Alden biesen](http://www.alden-biesen.be/) is worth the detour

And last but not least, Belgium has its [Ardennes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/6812/141)

A very interesting detour might be [Baarle Hertog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baarle-Hertog)/[Baarle Nassau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baarle-Nassau). Here you'll witness a bizar case of borders between two countries [image: Screen dump of google maps]
Only here you can walk in a strait line an cross the border between two countries multiple times.

Comment: thank you for your time and effort. Your post is really useful and I will definitely visit some of the places you've listed out.