# Must see places while going through Germany (middle section)

Tags: sightseeing, road-trips, germany

I have asked the very same question about Belgium. I really liked the answers I got from [Must see places while going through Belgium](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7553/must-see-places-while-going-through-belgium)

**Edit:** I will be traveling by car from Baltics to Netherlands or Belgium with a group of 6 people, ages varies from 20 - 50. Our direction really depends on the weather and we'll start working our way back from there. One way or another we will be interested in the middle part of Germany (part between Hannover and Nürnberg).

We don't have anything special were interested in, we would just like to see as much as possible while driving back to the Baltics. Also we would like to avoid tourist traps where one could possibly spend a whole day, like amusement parks, big cities, bars & pubs etc.

We're looking sights where we could basically drive through (spend an hour or two and then move on). We're interested in anything that makes average Joe from another country go "wow" one way or another.

Earlier years we've used technique where we've looked POI's 50-100 km along the route from GPS and going through the country in a flowing manner.

Some style examples we've liked: Hill of crosses in Lithuania, Wieliczka salt mine, windmills in Netherlands, some great Castles, Nature beauty

[Answer I liked from Belgium thread](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/7560/2515)

What are a must-see places in Germany (middle section)?

Comment: Germany is a big country with many things to see. What kinds of things interest you the most— architecture, history, food, natural beauty? What time of year and what route will you take? What guide books or other resources have you consulted so far? Otherwise, it is not possible to answer such a question definitively. Please read the FAQ http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq .

Comment: To mention just one place: [Cologne Cathedral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cologne_Cathedral) (Kölner Dom) made me go "wow". It took more than 600 years to complete it, and back in 1880s it was the tallest building in the world.

Comment: It's safe to say that I'm interested in things that will make an average Joe go "wow!". Sometimes there are things that make it worth to make 300km detour - I'm looking thing like that. A must-see places.

Comment: Even so there are hundreds of things that make the average Jo(nik) go "wow".  As it stands this is still too broad a question. Germany is a MUCH bigger country than Belgium.  Are you after architecture? Churches? Rivers? Waterfalls? How much time do you have? The more detail in your question, the better it can be answered.

Comment: @Mark Mayo I've edited my question and also the heading.

Comment: It's nitpicking of course but the direct route would be crossing the North of Germany (culturally and geographically), not really the “Middle”. Nürnberg on the other hand is definitely in the South and geographically quite far East (even though it was obviously geopolitically in “the West” during the cold war) so there is really no unity whatsoever in the zone going “from Hannover to Nürnberg”.

Answer (score 10):

What you call the "middle section" is still quite vast. Here is a proposal.

From Belgium, you can transit via Luxembourg and then head to [Trier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trier), Germany's oldest city. It has among the finest Roman relics north of the Alps, such as e.g, an amphitheater and public bathes.

Continue southwards to Völklingen. There you can visit the famous and impressive [Völklinger Hütte](http://www.voelklinger-huette.org/en/welcome/) (Ironworks), an important piece of industrial heritage.

Then you will cross the [Pfalz (Palatinate)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatinate_%28region%29). On your way you can visit the [Trifels Castle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trifels_Castle). The Palatinate is home to some of Germany's finest red and white wines. Don't forget to try the [Saumagen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saumagen), a local specialty. The [Speyer cathedral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speyer_Cathedral) is worth a visit too.

Next head to Nürnberg. If you are interested, you can can pay a visit to the [technical museum in Sinsheim](http://www.technik-museum.de/en). The famous [Hockenheim Ring](http://www.hockenheimring.net/en) is on your way too. Depending on the agenda and your interests it might be worth a stop.

[Nürnberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg) has a nice old town dominated by the [imperial castle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_Castle). For me, the most impressive sight is the [Nazi Party Rally Ground](http://www.museums.nuremberg.de/documentation-centre/index.html) ([Reichsparteitagsgelände](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_party_rally_grounds)). Definitely worth a stop and even a detour.

Some 60 kilometers north of Nürnberg, stop in [Bamberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamberg). This city has quite a big and well-preserved historical center. Very picturesque.

My next stop would be [Dresden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dresden), with its world famous historical monuments (Frauenkirche, Zwinger, ...).

After Dresden, and beofre going to Poalnd, go to the [Spreewald](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreewald). This is a very special place. After the driving so much you will be able to breathe some fresh air. In Summer you can have a [boat tour](http://www.spreewald.de/active-fit/exploring-by-water/index.html) on the numerous waterways. In Winter, ice-skates are indicated rather than punts.

Comment: The Nazi Party Rally Ground is definitely one of the best spots in Germany, worth at least half of the day.

Answer (score 6):

Since Bayreuth lies almost directly in your path of travel, you would almost certainly want to take in the [Margravial Opera House](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margravial_Opera_House), which is one of the most dazzling examples of high baroque architecture in central Europe.  The inside of the threatre is breath-takingly opulent. [Bayreuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayreuth) also has a few other 'surprises', not to mention [Bavarian cuisine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlachtsch%C3%BCssel).  Avoid Bayreuth in August.

Answer (score 5):

The [Landschaftspark in Duisburg](http://en.landschaftspark.de/startseite) is an outstanding place on the industrial route. It's an old, closed steel mill with surrounding buildings. It's free and open round-the-clock, which makes it a thrilling experience as you walk up one of the towers in the middle of the night and completely on your own. It's nicely lit, but you'd better take a torch.

[image: Landschaftspark Duisburg-Nord]

Answer (score 4):

Driving along the Rhine river (between Mainz and Koblenz), there are a lot of "must-see-places" especially [Rüdesheim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%BCdesheim_am_Rhein) and [Loreley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loreley). I have been there more than 20 times, and I am still loving it